# what is the right json configuration script to configure code runner to run in visual studios? how do i remove the errors below?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

json error:

### End of file expected.

visual studio error:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qVRe.png

---

i found the following code in the extensions sections, after i installed code runner in visual studios. i didn't copy all of it, because i saw, there were useless configuration commands,to configure the code runner to run the code runner,so i didn't waste time with the useless commands and i decided to take the most useful configuration commands for code runner available.

here is my json configuration script for lunching code runner:
"pre launchTask": "g++.exe build active file",

```
        }
    {
{
  }
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
        "python": "python",
        "perl": "perl",
        "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
        "go": "go run",
        "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt" }
{                   
    "code-runner.executorMapByGlob": 
        "pom.xml": "cd $dir && mvn clean package",
        "*.test.js": "tap",
        "*.js": "node"      }
{

    "code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": 
        ".vbs": "cscript //Nologo"
                                                 }
{
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true
}
     {
    "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "c++"
                                             }   }

{
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true
                                             }
      {
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false
}
    {
    "code-runner.enableAppInsights": true
                                            }
```

Comment: If the code you posted is even a portion of a JSON file, there are a lot of missing commas and mismatched braces. Please run your configuration file through a JSON validator before posting! (eg: https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: thanks, i will do so.

Comment: @andyvanee if i were to get more validation errors, and i had enough solving the validation errors and if i were to give you the script that has been improved from before,with improved being defined as with less errors, would you be ok to continue removing the validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the right configuration script:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
"customLaunchSetupCommands": [
    { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
  ],
  "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
windows "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
  }
}

            "name": "(gdb) Bash on Windows Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "pipeTransport": {
                "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
                "pipeProgram": "${env:windir}\\system32\\bash.exe",
                "pipeArgs": ["-c"],
                "pipeCwd": ""
            },
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]"customLaunchSetupCommands": [
    { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
  ],
  "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
windows "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
  }
}
        },



}
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
        "python": "python",
        "perl": "perl",
        "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
        "go": "go run",
        "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
{
    "code-runner.executorMapByGlob": {
        "pom.xml": "cd $dir && mvn clean package",
        "*.test.js": "tap",
        "*.js": "node"
    }
}
{
    "code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
        ".vbs": "cscript //Nologo"
    }
}
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true
}
{
    "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "json"
}

{
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true
}
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false
}
{
    "code-runner.enableAppInsights": true
}

"customLaunchSetupCommands": [
    { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
  ],
  "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
windows "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
  }
}
```